# Symfony / Php 8 @Assert\Type("string") is really useful?

Tags: php-8, symfony6

Is it useful to use an assert type string when using php 8 types ?

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING)]
#[Assert\Type(type: 'string')]
protected string $title = '';
```

instead of

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING)]
protected string $title = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

A typed property can only be assigned values of the same type. Another value would either be silently converted, or crash the program. As such the type is guaranteed to be correct, **which makes the `Type` assertion useless**.

Also, note that it is better to validate data before they make their way inside your entities. Otherwise, it means your entities can be invalid and you’re just a validator call away to persist wrong data.